# Adding an element to my JSON object adds doublequotes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Trying to add a new element to a json file with newtonsoft. Console output seems fine at first but after adding the element i get double quotes or \"

```
public class ApplicationType
{
    public int action { get; set; }
    public List<string> extensions { get; set; }
    public List<Handler> handlers { get; set; }
}

public class Handler
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
}


string handlers = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\handlers.json");
Handler h = new Handler();
h.name = "Test";
h.path = @"C:\Test.exe";

ApplicationType a = new ApplicationType();
a.action = 2;
a.extensions = new List<String> { "test", "type" };
a.handlers = new List<Handler> { h};

Dictionary<String, ApplicationType> ad = new Dictionary<String, ApplicationType>();
ad.Add("application/test", a);

//Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ad));

JObject hndlr = JObject.Parse(handlers);
JObject mime = (JObject)hndlr["mimeTypes"];
mime.Add("application/test", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a));

File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\abc.json", hndlr.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(hndlr.ToString());
```

Console output without adding the object to the existing json:
`{"application/test":{"action":2,"extensions":["test","type"],"handlers":[{"name":"Test","path":"C:\\Test.exe"}]}}`

Console output and content from the text file after adding the element:
`"application/test": "{\"action\":2,\"extensions\":[\"test\",\"type\"],\"handlers\":[{\"name\":\"Test\",\"path\":\"C:\\\\Test.exe\"}]}"`

Solution: Replace `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a)` with `JToken.FromObject(a)`

Comment: You have to add to your question   ApplicationType and Handler classes. I can not see them in your json string

Comment: You need to share a [mcve] (see [ask]) but you **probably** want to do `mime.Add("application/test", JToken.FromObject(a))`.  `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a)` creates a string, then `hndlr.ToString()` formats `hndlr` as JSON which serializes the string a second time.

Answer (score 0):

@dbc was right. I needed to do `JToken.FromObject(a)` instead of serializing it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).